# Find the startpoint and endpoint of a Polyline

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of points that reside on a `Polyline`. The points in the list are not in order. How can I find the startpoint and endpoint of the `Polyline` (preferably using `LINQ`)

```
public class Point
{    
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}

var PointsOnPolyline = new List<Point>
{
    new Point { X = 300, Y = 400 },
    new Point { X = 0, Y = 400 },
    new Point { X = 1200, Y = 500 },
    new Point { X = 700, Y = 400 }
};

FinalResult = {P(0,400), P(1200,500)}
```

Comment: starting point will always be with x = 0 ??

Comment: Polyline means a line passing through multiple points? Then you can't know... You can draw a nonstraight line through any group of points in any order

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is ill-posed. "The polyline"? Which polyline? In your example, there are 4!/2 = 12 different possible polylines.

If you assume that the points on the polyline have strictly increasing X values, then you could do the following.

```
var orderedPoints = PointsOnPolyline.OrderBy(p => p.X);
var firstPoint = orderedPoints.First();
var lastPoint = orderedPoints.Last();
```

Comment: it is not necessary that starting point will always be with x =0

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I'm not making that assumption.

Comment: if that is the case what could be possible solution

Comment: Yes the Xs are increasing I forgot to include it.